# How can I specifiy attr_accessible for a nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, attr-accessible

From the docs, I see that if I have a model:

```
User has_many Addresses
```

that I can do this:

```
class User < AR::Base

  attr_accessible :addresses_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses

end
```

that I should be able to set those attributes from User. But I can't. Do I also need to add an "attr_accessible" callout in the Address model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to set attr_accessible on the Address model as well.

When ActiveRecord initializes an instance using a hash of attributes it will throw an exception when an attribute which has not been marked by attr_accessible is a part of the hash keys. Since in associations ActiveRecord objects are initialized with a hash of attributes there's no escaping from stating those attributes inside the Address model with attr_accessible.